# Access MBean from Application on Websphere 8

Tags: jmx, websphere-8, jconsole

I am trying to access a MBean from an Appication on a Websphere 8.0 server via JConsole (IBM Version).
Connecting to it via the PID works just fine and I can work with my MBean. 
The problem is the remote access. I tried to connect via

```
service:jmx:iiop://localhost:2809/jndi/JMXConnector
```

and on port 9100 but both times (after fixing the security-stuff) I only access the Websphere itself and not my own MBean.

What am I missing? How can I connect remotly to my application?

I contacted IBM on this matter but they only told me that JConsole isn't a IBM Product (even though it is shipped with Websphere) and encouraged me to reproduce the problem with a selfwritten client.